# Databricks Golang client getting error when map has NULL values

Tags: go, databricks-sql

When there are NULL values in Databricks map/struct type. The `Scan` method, will translate it to Golang zero value rather than returning NULL.
This make it impossible for the client to know if the Databricks saves zero value or null for that field.
In case ALL the values of the map/struct are NULL, the scan will simply fail.

See below code:

```
func selectFromMap(db *sql.DB) {
    var row interface{}

/********************************* Basic map ************************************/
    rows, err := db.Query("select map('red', 1, 'green', 2) as sample_map")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    if rows.Next() {
        if err = rows.Scan(&row); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("basic map: %v\n", row) // Good! {"red":1,"green":2}
    }

/********************************* Map with null value ****************************/
    rows, err = db.Query("select map('red', 1, 'green', null) as sample_map")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if rows.Next() {
        if err = rows.Scan(&row); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("map with null value: %v\n", row) // Bad! {"red":1,"green":0} -> should print NULL not 0 
    }

/***************************** Map with ONLY null values *************************/
    rows, err = db.Query("select map('red', NULL, 'green', NULL) as sample_map")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if rows.Next() {
        if err = rows.Scan(&row); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("map with ONLY Null values: %v\n", row) // ERR databricks: arrow row scanner unhandled type null
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
basic map: {"red":1,"green":2}
map with null value: {"red":1,"green":null}
map with ONLY Null values: {"red":NULL,"green":NULL}
```

Actual output:

```
basic map: {"red":1,"green":2}
map with null value: {"red":1,"green":0}
11:50AM ERR databricks: arrow row scanner unhandled type null connId=*** corrId= queryId=****
```

This there a config that can be used, so it will work properly also with NULL values?

Comment: report problem at https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-go

Comment: @AlexOtt I did https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-go/issues/126